# Get serverUrl from Apex

Tags: apex, soap-api

Let's say there is need to obtain org link (like  https:///services/Soap/u/50.0)
using APEX code?
The main purpose is to provide this value to 3rd party app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider the URL class.  Here is the documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_url.htm

Comment: do i need to add `/services/soap/u/50.0` always? or there is another way to retrieve full path?

Comment: @PeterNoges please don't use screenshots for documentation since this does not help visually impaired people (screen readers won't typically be able to read the text). Better to copy/paste the text as a quote and to include a link to the source of that documentation.

Comment: @pincet the base URL for an org does not direct you to any specific service; you must always add the required path onto the end of the URL to identify the service you want to invoke.